# How to set node-exporter of Prometheus

Tags: docker-compose, docker-swarm, grafana, prometheus-node-exporter

How to set node-exporter of Prometheus for collecting host metrics in docker-swarm

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  node-exporter:
    image: prom/node-exporter
    volumes:
      - /proc:/host/proc:ro
      - /sys:/host/sys:ro
      - /:/rootfs:ro
    command:
      - '--path.procfs=/host/proc'
      - '--path.sysfs=/host/sys'
      - --collector.filesystem.ignored-mount-points
      - "^/(sys|proc|dev|host|etc|rootfs/var/lib/docker/containers|rootfs/var/lib/docker/overlay2|rootfs/run/docker/netns|rootfs/var/lib/docker/aufs)($$|/)"
      - '--collector.textfile.directory=/etc/node-exporter/'                    
      - '--collector.enabled="conntrack,diskstats,entropy,filefd,filesystem,loadavg,mdadm,meminfo,netdev,netstat,stat,textfile,time,vmstat,ipvs"'
    ports:
      - 9100:9100
```

i am getting this error:- node_exporter: error: unknown long flag '--collector.enabled', try --help
what's wrong about last line under command section in this docker-compose file & if wrongly set/passed, how to pass it correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use --collector.[collector_name] (e.g. --collector.diskstats) keys instead of --collector.enabled as it does not work anymore since 0.15 version or higher.

Answer (score 1):

For multiple collectors you can try as below after version "< 0.15":

```
--collector.processes --collector.ntp  ...... so on
```

In the older version " > 0.15 " we were using as below for specific collectors:

```
--collectors.enabled meminfo,loadavg,filesystem
```